# Post request with form data raising 400 error in mocha test

Tags: node.js, docker, mocha.js

I am trying to run test cases within the server using docker containers. While I am trying to test a post request with the image field along with the other field raising bad request **400** all the time. The service seems like working fine for other requests. I am posting the snippet of code here.

```
 it('company  registartion', function(done){
request(app).post('/companies/')
    .set({apikey: 'TestHashKey',headers: headers})
    .type('form')
     .send({"name": "Test_company", "phoneNumber": "+123456741538", "logo":'/app/test/images/company_logo.jpg'})
     .expect(200)
     .end(function(err,res) {
                    if (err) {
                            throw err;
                    }
      done();
      });
    });
```

**And the response is attaching here.**

```
 GMT uncaughtException: expected 200 "OK", got 400 "Bad Request"
```

Comment: Did you set 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data' in the header?

Comment: yes I  have tried that too.

Comment: Can you provide code for your service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the POST request body contains an image the images can be attached by **.attach("field":"absolute path of the image")**. It can be like the following code.

```
it("user test ", function(done){
request(app).post('/user')
    .field('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
    .field('name', 'xyz')
    .field('phoneNumber','+258114311354')
    .attach("logo","test/images/user.jpg") 
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err,res) {
       if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      done();
      });
});
```